# Date comparison in excel question

Tags: excel

I am trying to compare dates within an excel spreadsheet. The first column is the date/time the Windows user profile service starts. The second column is the date/time a particular service initiates a system shutdown. I want to create a report of all the dates that do not have a date in the second column between two consecutive dates in the first.

Any ideas on how this could be most easily accomplished? Any suggestions on where to start? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show a sample of the 3 columns?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you put some of your data here and gave an example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: "All the dates that do not have a date in the second column between two consecutive dates in the first" doesn't make sense. If the first column is just a single date, where do you get the 'two' dates? An example would help greatly.

Answer (score 1):

I asume your list is sorted on the 1st column and all date/time are really recognized as date/time by Excel (i.e. numeric). Now you want to find all rows without a shutdown date where the next row's starting date is 1 higher as this row's starting date ... meaning the integer part of next row's date/time is exactly 1 more than the integer part of this row's date/time

Create a new column "Condition" containing the formula

```
[C2]    =AND((B2="");INT(A3)-INT(A2)=1)
```

and copy it all the way down; then use an Autofilter and filter for "TRUE"

example:

```
    [A]                     [B]                     [C v]          [D]
----------------------.-----------------------.----------------.----------------------------
[1] startup           .     shutdown          .     condition  .   comment
[2] 10.09.2011 17:45  .     10.09.2011 18:21  .     FALSE      .
[3] 11.09.2011 15:50  .     11.09.2011 16:26  .     FALSE      .
[4] 12.09.2011 13:55  .                       .     TRUE       .
[5] 13.09.2011 12:00  .     13.09.2011 12:36  .     FALSE      .
[6] 14.09.2011 11:59  .                       .     FALSE      .   next row is same date
[7] 14.09.2011 14:08  .     14.09.2011 14:44  .     FALSE      .
```

I hope I understood your problem correctly ....